# error: from keras.preprocessing.text import base_filter

Tags: python, keras

I just started using Keras. Just tried to import base_filter for text preprocessing. I did:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import base_filter
```

I got error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Base_filter'
```

surprisingly, I did google search and could not find any answers to that. Anyone knows what went wrong?  where is base_filter located in keras

thanks  a lot.

Comment: please specify your environment, versions of keras , backend and so on. :)

Comment: keras version 2.0.0      I'm using jupyter notebook.  Backend is tensorflow.

Comment: Is the answer helpful? :-) see below if you haven't seen it yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this is an error coming from the new version of Keras (2.0). The change is recent and tutorials/documentation might not be up to date.

We had before ([like in the doc](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/)) that the default value for `filter=` argument in text preprocessing functions was a function "`base_filter()`" this function would contain a list of special chars to remove.

In the new version, as you can see in the source code, the default filter is not `base_filter()` function anymore but directly a list :

```
def text_to_word_sequence(text,
                          filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n',
                          lower=True, split=" "):
    """Converts a text to a sequence of word indices.
    # Arguments
        text: Input text (string).
        filters: Sequence of characters to filter out.
        lower: Whether to convert the input to lowercase.
        split: Sentence split marker (string).
    # Returns
        A list of integer word indices.
    """
```

see the [full code here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/text.py#L22).

So to summarize, the doc isn't up to date, the function `base_filter()` doesn't exist anymore in Keras 2.0. The characters filtered by the base_filter is simply replaced by the list of characters : `'!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n'`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Great help! @Nassim Ben